# accord et infinitif du passé

Tags: accord

> J'espère les avoir bien écrites. (*)

*Les* est un complément d'objet direct féminin pluriel.

1) L'accord de l'infinitif passé (actif) est-il correct ?

2) Peut-on utiliser cette tournure ou celle ci-dessous est-elle plus appropriée ?

> J'espère que je les ai bien écrites.

3) Dans la phrase originale (*) la position de *les* est-elle correcte ?

Comment: Comme tu le sais en tant que membre expérimenté, il vaut mieux ajouter un peu sur la cause de la difficulté : qu'est-ce que tu as compris jusqu'ici, comment l'as-tu appliqué à l'affaire en cours, pourquoi n'es-tu pas sûr que tu l'as fait de la bonne manière, etc. Comme ça la question pourra servir à plus que la vérification d'un seul cas.

Comment: Tu as raison. Je vais la modifier. Merci:-)!

Comment: C'est une amélioration !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, c'est tout à fait correct.

- Le pronom *les* se place bien entre le verbe espérer et l’auxiliaire avoir.
- L'accord du participe passé se fait avec le COD placé avant le verbe avoir :

  J'ai écrit quoi ? Les lettres (par exemple). Il faut que l'on sache au préalable que *les* représente un substantif féminin.

En français courant, on entendra plus souvent:

> J'espère que je les ai bien écrites.